# How to make a row clickable to view details

Tags: grails, view

I have a list of items I am showing and I want to make the whole row clickable but right now I just have the first column clickable. Once the row is clicked I would like to see it go to a buy ticket page where I can add more details like ticket price, seat numbers and all that sort of detail. Right now when the link is clicked it just throw an error:

```
--------------------------------
HTTP Status 404 - /tictoc/store/detail/7
type Status report
message /tictoc/store/detail/7
description The requested resource (/tictoc/store/detail/7) is not available.
--------------------------------
```

Here is the controller. I added a details def, where I try to forward to store/buy page. I assume this will take the id from the params obj and get the single items and forward to the buy page. I am also curious why the log.error does not show up in the output as the code runs. Wish there was a way to make logging less clumsy in grails, since turning on info just amounts to huge amounts of logging using error seemed the least annoying option.

```
package tictoc
import tictoc.Event 
class StoreController {
    Event event
    static defaultAction = "activeEvents"
    def show = {
        log.error 'exec activeEvents'
        activeEvents()
    }

    def activeEvents = {
        log.error 'exec activeEvents'

        def max    = Math.min(params.int('max', 5), 100);
        def offset = params.offset?.toInteger() ?: 0
        def total =  Event.count()
        def eventList = Event.list(max: params.max, offset: params.offset)

        return [events:eventList, 
                       totalEvents:total,
                       active:params.active]                  
    }

    def detail = {
        log.error 'exec detail'
        def eventId = params.id
        log.error 'eventId:' + eventId
        render(view: "buy", model: [event: eventId])
    }

    def list = {
        params.max = Math.min(params.int('max', 25), 100);
        params.offset = params.int('offset', 0)
        params.sort = params.sort ?: "name";
        params.order = params.order ?: "asc";
        return [ myList: DomainObject.list(params) ]
    }
}
```

Here is the show.gsp where I put the link to the items I want users to click on to buy/reserve tickets. I wish I could make the whole row clickable not just the first column. Not sure how much more description is needed but this submission process is tedious so I am adding more details just to submit.

```
<%@ page import="tictoc.Store" %>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="layout" content="main">
        <g:set var="entityName" value="${message(code: 'store.label', default: 'Store')}" />
        <title><g:message code="default.show.label" args="[entityName]" /></title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <h1> Ticket Store </h1>
        <div>
            <table border=0 class="eventsTable">
                <tr>

                    <th>Event</th>
                    <th>Start </th>
                    <th>End </th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                </tr>
                <g:each var="event" in="${events}">

                <tr>
                    <td><g:link action="detail" controller="store" id="${event.id}">
                        ${event.name}
                        </g:link>
                    </td>
                    <td><g:formatDate format="MM/dd/yyyy" date="${event.startDate}"/></td>
                    <td><g:formatDate format="MM/dd/yyyy" date="${event.endDate}"/></td>
                    <td>${event.desc}</td>
                </tr>

                </g:each>
            </table>

        </div>
        <div class="paginateButtons">
            <g:paginate controller="store"
                action="show"
                max="5"
                params="[name:active]"
                total="${totalEvents}" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the buy ticket page inside the store folder I don't have much more than a stub at this point but I want to add a buy button that will attempt to add this ticket to some kind of shopping cart and allow for payment after all shopping is complete:

```
<%@ page import="tictoc.Store" %>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="layout" content="main">
        <g:set var="entityName" value="${message(code: 'store.label', default: 'Store')}" />
        <title><g:message code="default.show.label" args="[entityName]" /></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1> Ticket Store </h1>
        <table border=0 class="eventsTable">
            <tr>
                <th>Event</th>
                <th>Start </th>
                <th>End </th>
                <th>Description</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>${event.name}</td>
                <td><g:formatDate format="MM/dd/yyyy" date="${event.startDate}"/></td>
                <td><g:formatDate format="MM/dd/yyyy" date="${event.endDate}"/></td>
                <td>${event.desc}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        BUY TICKET
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To make the row clickable, you'd probably need to use some JavaScript.  Here is an un-tested jquery example:

```
<tr class="clickable" data-id="${event.id}">
  ...
</tr>

$(".clickable").on("click", function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   window.location = "/store/detail/" + $(this).data("id");
});
```

Comment: what about the part where the link does not show the actual purchase page? That is throwing the 404 error. The javascript did not seem to work either:

Comment: <pre>
   <%@ page import="tictoc.Store" %>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="layout" content="main">
        <g:set var="entityName" value="${message(code: 'store.label', default: 'Store')}" />
        <title><g:message code="default.show.label" args="[entityName]" /></title>
        
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(".clickable").on("click", function(e) {
               e.preventDefault();
               window.location = "/store/detail/" + $(this).data("id");
            });
        </script>
    </head>

Comment: <table border=0 class="eventsTable">
.
.
                <g:each var="event" in="${events}">
                <tr class="clickable" data-id="${event.id}">
                    <td>${event.name}</td>
                    <td><g:formatDate format="MM/dd/yyyy" date="${event.startDate}"/></td>
                    <td><g:formatDate format="MM/dd/yyyy" date="${event.endDate}"/></td>
                    <td>${event.desc}</td>
                </tr>
                </g:each>
            </table>

Comment: So far this has not been useful.

Comment: I disagree but feel free to wait on a different answer.  I don't know why your edit action isn't working.  I see nothing wrong with anything, at least nothing that stands out.  You didn't even tell me if the code I provided helped or not.  So you're not being very helpful either.